# How do I change field handler_settings within hook_form_alter?

Tags: 8, entities, ajax

I have an entity reference field that is inside of a field_collection (D8) and I need to alter it's views arguments during ajax load to pass in the value from a preceding field on the host entity. I have everything working except I am not sure how to change the handler_settings on the field_collections entity reference.

```
Node
  - field_a: contains argument to pass to field_c
  - field_b: field_collection_item
    - field_c: entity reference field using a view for it's available options. Need to pass in views arguments to this field's handler_settings whenever I ajax load field_b.
```

So far I have field_b properly ajaxing in, but I am not sure how to alter the handler_settings. I have this to obtain the current handler_settings:

```
  $field_name = 'field_c';
  $bundle_fields = \Drupal::getContainer()->get('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('field_collection_item', 'field_b');
  $field_definition = $bundle_fields[$field_name];
  $field_project_handler_settings = $field_definition->getSetting('handler_settings');
```

The output of `$field_project_handler_settings` is:

[image: kint output]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: After thinking about this some more I might have found a solution. I am going the route of creating a custom field type for this field where I might be able to override the argument settings when I extend the `EntityReferenceItem` class to create my field type. Anyone have an opinion on this idea?

Comment: Also, I now thought about something maybe even simpler, provide a custom token that passes the needed value through the arguments. I am already running a [patch on Drupal core to allow for this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1699378#comment-10797676). Trying this first.

Comment: Well, while coding this token module I realized that the entity is not yet created so the token value won't likely exist. I need to do the field type I think. Trying that now.

Comment: Hi @nicholas.alipaz Have you found solution to change field handler_settings within hook_form_alter? I have to create new Widget and have done modifications in that widget. To achieve this https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/258138/restrict-creation-of-new-taxonomy-terms-via-node-form-through-entity-reference-f/258187#258187 Please answer / suggest if you are able to alter settings. Thanks :)