# Restrict creation of new taxonomy terms via node form through entity reference filed (autocomplete) for particular user role

Tags: 8, entities

I have Entity reference field (taxonomy terms ) in node form.

I have checked the option (***Create referenced entities if they don't already exist***) so that users can create new taxonomy terms in field of node form i.e.: on creation on node new terms creation is allowed.

[image]

Looks like below in Node Form:

[image]

But I want to alter this and make restricted to certain roles. So that user with particular role should not be able to create new terms and must select from existing node.

> My field is 
>   core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/EntityReferenceAutocompleteWidget.php

While going thorugh code it seems under :

```
[#selection_settings] => Array
                        (
                            [target_bundles] => Array
                                (
                                    [topic] => topic
                                )

                            [sort] => Array
                                (
                                    [field] => name
                                    [direction] => asc
                                )

                            [auto_create] => 1
                            [auto_create_bundle] => 
                            [match_operator] => CONTAINS
                        )
```

***[auto_create] => 1***  I tried to alter this by adding contain of user role in node form alter, but not its not working the value get changed.

Please suggest !

**Update :** **Please see @ssibal**

[image]

```
    drupal config-list field.field.node.link.field_topic2
 field.field.node.link.field_topic2                                                                                                                               
 uuid: f3c818dd-b5cd-4a73-af88-c20c1d0e24c3                                                                                                                       
 langcode: en                                                                                                                                                     
 status: true                                                                                                                                                     
 dependencies:                                                                                                                                                    
   config:                                                                                                                                                        
     - field.storage.node.field_topic2                                                                                                                            
     - node.type.link                                                                                                                                             
     - taxonomy.vocabulary.topic                                                                                                                                  
 id: node.link.field_topic2                                                                                                                                       
 field_name: field_topic2                                                                                                                                         
 entity_type: node                                                                                                                                                
 bundle: link                                                                                                                                                     
 label: Topic                                                                                                                                                     
 description: "Sätt flera olika ämnen, separera dem med kommatecken och inled med stor bokstav.\r\n<br>\r\nExempel: SEB, Fraktionella reserver, Svågerkapitalism" 
 required: true                                                                                                                                                   
 translatable: false                                                                                                                                              
 default_value: {  }                                                                                                                                              
 default_value_callback: ''                                                                                                                                       
 settings:                                                                                                                                                        
   handler: 'default:taxonomy_term'                                                                                                                               
   handler_settings:                                                                                                                                              
     target_bundles:                                                                                                                                              
       topic: topic                                                                                                                                               
     sort:                                                                                                                                                        
       field: name                                                                                                                                                
       direction: asc                                                                                                                                             
     auto_create: true                                                                                                                                            
     auto_create_bundle: ''                                                                                                                                       
 field_type: entity_reference
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, but I think the most clean is: 
[Config Override](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/configuration-override-system).

I suggest to read the whole to understand it, but only this part is needed for you: **Providing overrides from modules**

You need then only find the configuration you want to override in runtime, and do it based on the current user role.

The field config pattern you are looking for is the following:
**field.field.entity_type.bundle.field_name**

The *auto_create* is under '*settings/handler_settings*'.

**HOW TO FIND AND EXAMINE THE CONFIGS YOU NEED**

Configs are also entities. They can be feetched with EntityTypeManager.
To see what type of entities you have in the system you have the "getDefinitions()" method. Then all you have to do, is to find the right storage (`getStorage($config_entity_type)`), and then load it by ID.
Printing it out with kint, will give you a nice overview how the entity looks like, and how the settings are stored.

You can also "drush cex" your configuration. In this case configuration files will be created. The same scheme can be also found here. It gives also a good overview.

Comment: Thanks for guidance, I have tested the way you suggested. Similar to example I am able to override site name, please suggest how should I find configuration name. when I used **_drush config-list_** it listed : **_field.storage.node.field_topic2_** and **_field.field.node.link.field_topic2_** only  but this does not seems to show any value such as **_auto_create_**. Please suggest.

Comment: dependencies:
  config:
    - field.storage.node.field_topic2
    - node.type.link
    - taxonomy.vocabulary.topic
id: node.link.field_topic2
field_name: field_topic2
entity_type: node
bundle: link
label: Topic
required: true
translatable: false
default_value: {  }
default_value_callback: ''
settings:
  handler: 'default:taxonomy_term'
  handler_settings:
    target_bundles:
      topic: topic
    sort:
      field: name
      direction: asc
    **auto_create: true**
    auto_create_bundle: ''
field_type: entity_reference

Comment: Seems like similar to https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194796/how-do-i-change-field-handler-settings-within-hook-form-alter

Comment: **drush config-get system.site** gives values but **drush config-get node.link.field_topic2** comes as does not exist in active configuration but similarly  **drush config-get field.storage.node.field_topic2** gives values. Seems like this is not part of config but some kind of handler settings. Please suggest !

Comment: I have to create new Field widget and made required changes in formElement of widget based on user role. Hope there is any better solution than this I have to use for now.

Comment: Thanks for you help so far +1 I am still not sure how to fetch in config way. I am able to print the values and change them as well but not thorugh config, `$bundle_fields = \Drupal::getContainer()->get('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions("node", "link");
    $field_definition = $bundle_fields['field_topic2'];
    $handler_settings = $field_definition->getSetting('handler_settings');` could you please see from this code commented and help me to get config in my class implementing ConfigFactoryOverrideInterface

Comment: I have updated in answer but there is problem the override worked but it seems only overrding  remains in action always , seems some cache etc effect it  (not sure, I have listed how I did according to your suggestion in my answer. Sorry for troubling again )

Comment: " but it seems only overrding remains in action always , seems some cache etc effect it"
Can you rephrase this please? I can't understand it.

Comment: I mean to say after overriding like mentioned below in my answer with config override the way you suggested. The new terms creation got denied as  required but it does not respect role ie: it is denying every role to not allow adding new terms. So I though might be there is some cache etc or I am doing something wrong.  (Please see 3rd method code in my answer how I did by config override)

Comment: For more clear example I changed label : `$overrides = $overrides + [
            'field.field.node.link.field_topic2' => [
              'label' => 'changed via config',
            ],
          ];` but this does not work based on role ie: always new overridden label is shown to users. we can not show the label conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve it by 2 methods :

***First*** : http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal%21core%21modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter/8

```
function my_module_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {


if ($element['target_id']['#type'] == 'entity_autocomplete' && $element['target_id']['#target_type'] == 'taxonomy_term' && !empty($element['target_id']['#selection_settings']['target_bundles']['topic'])) {

$current_user = \Drupal::currentUser();
$roles = $current_user->getRoles();

    if(!in_array(ROLE_ADMIN, $roles)){
      if (!in_array('my_role', $roles) || in_array('anonymous', $roles)) {
        unset($element['target_id']['#autocreate']);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***Second***

By creating my own widget simialr to Autocomplete tag style and overriding formElement in that to remove auto_create fields support based on user role.

***Third:***

```
As suggested by @ssibal [Config Override.][1] (but problem in this )

$current_user = \Drupal::currentUser();
    $roles = $current_user->getRoles();

    if (!in_array('my_role', $roles)) {
        $overrides = $overrides + [
            'field.field.node.link.field_topic2' => [
              'settings' => ['handler_settings' => ['auto_create' => 0 ]],
            ],
          ];
     }


        return $overrides;
```

Comment: You can also solve it by this. However this solution is not as robust as the config override one.

Comment: I tried but it was not listed in config, please suggest if we can solve it with config overriding , I have mentioned in comments that it was not part of config.

Comment: @ssibal I have update config related to field. The config debug only show few things but not related to auto_create part which I need to override. May be I am missing some part which is not clear to me , please suggest if we can do it with config overrding

Comment: I updated my answer this morning: did you try those?